# Did men wear veils in Tanach?

Tags: tanach, clothing, men-male, face

Besides Moshe is there any record of any other male wearing a veil or other face covering in tanach?

Comment: Interesting question, but presumably no one else wore one. Even Moshe didn't wear it due to any 'religious' reasons, he wore it simply to cover the 'holy light' emanating from his face, and allow others to look at him without harm. As an aside, I recall hearing that when Moshe would teach Bnei Yisrael, he removed the veil, as the people at that moment were on a high enough level to be able to perceive the 'light' without harm. As there is no other person (to the best of my knowledge) who exuded a 'light of holiness' like Moshe, presumably no one else wore a veil.

Comment: You may want to edit in the source that Moshe wore a veil. It was not apparent to me until I saw the comment.

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: pretty sure Elisha wore a veil. will look for the source

Comment: @rikitikitembo do you know the source for that?

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Not veils, but other face coverings:

David, after Avshalom's death: והמלך לאט את פניו (II Shmuel 19:5)

Eliyahu at Har Chorev: וילט פניו באדרתו (I Melachim 19:13)

Michayhu for his "playact" to Achav: ויתחפש באפר על עיניו (I Melachim 20:38)

Yechezkel during his "playacting" of Tzidkiyahu's flight: פניך תכסה (Yechezkel 12:6), and Tzidkiyahu himself: פניו יכסה (Yechezkel 12:12)

Comment: these are not instances of people wearing veils, but rather covering their faces. I am asking for examples of men wearing a veil specifically

Comment: @user9953 "a veil or other face covering," you wrote.

Comment: fair. I've edited.

Comment: @user9953 looks like your edit was rolled back. But look, if you're asking specifically for a veil (מסוה), then indeed there's no other example in Tanach - the word itself is a hapax, appearing only in this passage.